# refresh load redirection logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net mvc application. i have an authentification form : so i used a static class which contains a static boolean that indicates the connectivty of the user:

```
 public static class CompteModels
    {
        private static bool connected = false;

        public static bool Connected
        {
            get { return CompteModels.connected; }
            set { CompteModels.connected = value; }
        }
    }
```

In the controller i have this snippet:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Upload.Models.CompteModels.Connected)
            {
                return View();
            }

            else return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            Upload.Models.CompteModels.Connected = false;
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");


        }
```

the problem is : when i log in to my account then i logout if i did `come back to the previous page` my account page is reopened (the redirection to home page didn't work)
except i refresh the page.
What is the problem and how can i coorect my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that the page is cached and the user is seeing the cached page. It isn't actually making the request to your site. If you don't want any of your site cached so they always load the page from the server you can add the following attribute to all of your controllers or your base controller if you have one:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

You lose all bandwidth saving from cache but if you have highly sensitive data inside your site it might be worthwhile.

I have seen other "hacks" that involve making an ajax request on every page load and if it fails due to not being authorized it redirects to the login screen.

Comment: ok thanks, but can i block the action come back in the browser. because i'd like if i were connected and i click into come back the page still the same and i'am not redirecting to the home page of authentification?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking to do. With the solution I put above when the person logs off and they click the back button they will be redirected to whatever page you specified as your forms authentication page. Is that not what you want to happen?